# std::adjacent_difference with std::chrono time_point

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point> time;
    time.push_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4));
    time.push_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(7));
    time.push_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    std::vector<std::chrono::duration<double>> diffs;
    std::adjacent_difference(time.begin(),time.end(),std::back_inserter(diffs));
}
```

It does not compile(ugly template error message about mismatched types).
When I try to switch to type in the error message(`std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>>`) error message moves around.

My assumption is that algorithm does not work because result of substracting 2 timepoints is not a timepoint, i.e. this lines from pseudocode are conflicing.

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
constexpr // since C++20
OutputIt adjacent_difference(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
                             OutputIt d_first)
{
    if (first == last) return d_first;
 
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type value_t;
    value_t acc = *first;  
    *d_first = acc; // <-----------------------------------------------------  1
    while (++first != last) {
        value_t val = *first;
        *++d_first = val - std::move(acc); // std::move since C++20  <-------- 2
        acc = std::move(val);
    }
    return ++d_first;
}
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is my guess correct?
2. What is the simplest fix?  [Best](https://godbolt.org/z/R4qYAz) I can think of is ugly
   transform from timepoint to duration as a middlestep.

Although chrono is C++11 I am tagging this C++20 since I am open to any C++20 solutions, although I prefer them to not be ranges since they are not implemented in my compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My assumption is that algorithm does not work because result of substracting 2 timepoints is not a timepoint

Indeed, subtracting two `time_point`s does not yield a `time_point` - it yields a `duration`. In `<chrono>`, `duration`s and `time_point`s form an affine space. This is similar to how you cannot add two pointers, but you can subtract two pointers - and what you get isn't a pointer, you get a `ptrdiff_t`.

The `adjacent_difference` algorithm doesn't support affine types like this because given a range `[a, b, c]` the output is specified to be `[a, b-a, c-b]`. That basically cannot work because `a` and `b-a` have different, non-convertible types.

The simplest way to do this to probably use range-v3:

```
zip_with(minus(), time, time | drop(1))
```

Produces the adjacent difference you actually want - that doesn't include the first value (the `time_point`) so you just get a range of `duration`s.

---

There is a two-range version of [`transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) that I always forget about (thanks Conor). That works too:

```
std::transform(time.begin(), std::prev(time.end()), std::next(time.begin()),
    std::back_inserter(diffs), std::minus());
```

That's basically the "correct" version of `adjacent_difference`. In C++20, this can be a little clearer:

```cpp
std::ranges::transform(time | std::views::drop(1), time
    std::back_inserter(diffs), std::minus());
```

---

You could also completely abuse `adjacent_find`:

```
std::adjacent_find(time.begin(), time.end(), [&](auto t1, auto t2){
    diffs.push_back(t2 - t1);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: range-v3 means that Eric did not get it in C++20 I presume? Or you are referring to it since it is available now.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl There's no `zip`/`zip_with` in C++20.

Comment: Dang it, @Barry!  Posting your own, (better) answer while I'm writing mine. :-)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl ... but there is binary `transform`

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference):

> Computes the differences between the second and the first of each adjacent pair of elements of the range `[first, last)` and writes them to the range beginning at `d_first + 1`. An unmodified copy of `*first` is written to `*d_first`.

That last sentence is what's tripping you up.

Comment: This is actually quite amazing, I dont think I have ever seen any type in std:: that does not work with all algorithms(not talking about iterator requirements or move only types, just the fact that operations on type itself are problematic).

Comment: @Barry pointed out that raw pointers are another such type that have problems with `adjacent_difference` (since the difference of two pointers is of type `ptrdiff_t`)